# I switch from sqlite to postgres on heroku and my code stops working

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy

I started with sqlite, which worked perfectly, then switched to postgre, which began acting up. After switching back to sqlite, things resumed as normal. I'm new to heroku and postgresql ,please help

top code:

```
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL').replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = url
```

this is the error i keep getting back on heroku

```
[2022-07-21 23:38:25,671] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674368+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674373+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674374+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674380+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674380+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674381+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_posts" does not exist
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674381+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM blog_posts
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674382+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674382+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674382+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674382+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674382+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674383+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674383+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674384+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674384+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674384+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674385+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674385+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 82, in get_all_posts
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:     posts = BlogPost.query.all()
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3346, in all
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674386+00:00 app[web.1]:     return list(self)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3508, in __iter__
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3533, in _execute_and_instances
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674387+00:00 app[web.1]:     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:     ret = self._execute_context(
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674388+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.raise_(
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674390+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674390+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "blog_posts" does not exist
2022-07-21T23:38:25.674390+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM blog_posts
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_posts" does not exist`. You're trying to query a table that hasn't been created in your database.